# how to make a subquery using the query builder of laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to do the following mysql query with the query builder of Laravel 7:

```sql
SELECT r.id, (SELECT date FROM posts as pp where r.id = pp.request_id 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(pp.date, 1, 19),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') DESC limit 1), r.delivery_mode FROM requests AS r 
LEFT JOIN posts AS p ON r.id = p.request_id
group by r.id;
```

However unfortunately I don't understand how to obtain the latests post date for every request using the query builder of Laravel. I suppose I should do a subquery as in the query above. This is my code:

```php
$query = DB::table('requests'); 
$query->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(requests.id)'),'requests.delivery_mode',DB::raw('posts.date'));
$query->leftJoin('posts', 'requests.id', '=', 'posts.request_id');
$requests_list = $query->get();
```

In the table posts, the date is a string in this format: `2020-04-16T12:46:33+02:00`. So I used that complicated functions because I want to see only the latest date post grouped by `id_request`, that is the foreign key of the table posts connected with the primary key `id` of the table requests. A request can have many posts.

Can help?

**PS:**

I found the solution:

```
$query = DB::table('requests'); 
$query->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT(requests.id)'),'requests.delivery_mode',DB::raw("(SELECT date FROM posts as pp where requests.id = pp.request_id ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(pp.date, 1, 19),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') DESC limit 1) as lastPostDate"));
$query->leftJoin('posts', 'requests.id', '=', 'posts.request_id');
$requests_list = $query->get();
```

Probably it isn't a pretty solution but it works!.

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result since you have table p condition in the WHERE clause. Move to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: may I know what is the relation between request and post? line one to many or one to one, etc

Comment: One to many. One request can have many posts.

Comment: @jarlh I updated mysql query adding the left join. Is it a way to do the same with the query builder of Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

**Request Model**

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

**Post Model**

```php
public function request()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Request::class); 
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
   $date = Post::has("request")
               ->orderBy(...) // add your order by condition here
               ->limit(1)
               ->pluck("date");
   $requests = Request::with("posts")
                      ->where("date", $date)
                      ->get();
   return $requests; 
}
```